# GWT RequestFactory, how to override getters in EntityProxy?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am using GWT RequestFactory facility and I want share some code between client and server.
To achieve my goal, I implemented a common interface between client proxies and server domain classes.
So I have something like:

- common interfaces

  ```
  public interface IPerson {
      IColor getColor();
  }

  public interface IColor {
      String getColor();
  }
  ```
- domain classes

  ```
      public class Person implements IPerson {
           private Color color;
           public Color getColor() {
                 return color;
           }
      }

      public class Color implements IColor {
           private String color;
           public String getColor() {
                 return color;
           }
      }
  ```
- proxy interfaces

  ```
      @ProxyFor(Person.class)
      public interface PersonProxy extends EntityProxy, IPerson {
          ColorProxy getColor();
      }

      @ProxyFor(Color.class)
      public interface ColorProxy extends EntityProxy, IColor {
          String getColor();
      }
  ```

This only works when I use those proxies as return parameter types of RequestContext,
but when I try to pass a proxy as an argument type, like:

```
Request<Void> persist(PersonProxy personProxy);
```

I get an UnsupportedOperationException:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: com.example.IColor
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodex.getTypeOrDie(ValueCodex.java:375)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodex.decode(ValueCodex.java:299)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.EntityCodex.decode(EntityCodex.java:107)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor$1.visitReferenceProperty(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:545)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.traverseProperties(ProxyAutoBean.java:324)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.traverse(AbstractAutoBean.java:166)
    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean.accept(AbstractAutoBean.java:101)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processOperationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:524)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:218)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
```

The problem is that GWT does not "override" the getters, considering not only the PersonProxy

```
ColorProxy getColor();
```

but also his supertype counterpart

```
IColor getColor();
```

throwing the exeption because he cannot find a domain type for IColor.

The problem is that in [com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean.calculateData(Class beanType)](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/autobean/vm/impl/ProxyAutoBean.java?r=10344) the getters are populated using beanType.getMethods(), and I don't see any way to modify this behavior.

Is there a way to make gwt use only the most specific getter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think any interface that is inherited needs to extend from EntityProxy or ValueProxy. This is almost assuredly the issue you are having. Are you running the requestfactory validator. It seems like this would be throwing an error before you would be allowed to run the code?

Comment: The validator does not complain and indeed the issue is due to the fact tha my interfaces are not extending EntityProxy or ValueProxy.  I ended up using wrappers from proxies to interfaces.

Comment: @Gainder, could you please describe how did you fix the issue? It seems that we faced the same one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36714312/187241.

Answer (score 0):

What is your rationale for sharing the code between client and server? the premise of Request Factory is it separates your client from your server. On the client you use light weight interfaces that replicate the server side structure and thus allow your to separate the two concerns.

On the server you can have all heavy weight annotations, dependencies all sorts and on the client.

The other thing to bear in mind is that request factory treats your client dto's (interfaces) differently and traversal are managed. That is you can only traverse the tree on the client if you've already asked for RF to load the reference. Thus honouring the interface on the client would be problematic.